# Push onto array with find exec

Tags: bash, find, array, exec

I want to iterate over all the files found by `find` and add each one to an array. Here's what I have so far:

```
myarray=()
find . -name '*.php' -exec myarray\+=\({}\) \;
echo "${myarray[@]}"
```

Instead, it produces lots of this:

```
find: myarray+=(./somedir/somefile.php): No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to make this work with proper escaping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your aproach should  be as follow. To stay on your way of thinking you'd do something like:

```
myarray=()

while IFS= read -rd '' files; do myarray+=("$files")
 done < <(find . -type f -name '*.php' -print0)

printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}"
```

As a side note. You don't need to define `myarray=()` the array variable at all. You can leave that out.

Comment: My original intent with the array was to allow the `NUL` character in a filename. [From what I can tell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18218019/2407870), this approach does not allow them. Is that right?

Comment: File names [cannot have null bytes in them](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_267). Bash strings also cannot contain nulls.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius  This aproach does force `read` to use `NUL` byte as it's line delimiter. Since `NUL` is not a valid byte in unix filenames, this however is the safest place of feeding an array.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 for a better explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/326105/320092) made it sound as though `NUL` was allowed on Mac, but I guess it's just allowed by HFS+, but not by the OS.